# Active directory server is not operational. error code 2147016646

Tags: active-directory

New to C#.  I am trying to browse AD for a particular OU.  I get the following error. error code 2147016646.  I tried running the program with higher privl.  acct.  But still get the same error.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             string objectPath = "Server1";
             try
             {
                if (DirectoryEntry.Exists("LDAP://" + objectPath))
                    Console.WriteLine(objectPath + "exists");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine(objectPath + " does not exists");
            }
            catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
            }
        }      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will probably have to use something more than just "Server1" for your LDAP path.

Try something like:

```
string objectPath = "Server1/cn=Users,dc=yourcompany,dc=som";
try
{
   if (DirectoryEntry.Exists("LDAP://" + objectPath))
      Console.WriteLine(objectPath + "exists");
   else
      Console.WriteLine(objectPath + " does not exists");
}
```

This would check if the default "Users" container on your server exists (or not).

Marc